# Line chart in excel does not provide a line chart instead providing incorrect chart while using in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need Dates shown in x-axis and H, Q, and Vm shown in the y-axis of a line chart. So when I'm creating line chart by selecting all these three data's I'm getting a graph like this:

[image: But I don't want my graph to be like this]

But I don't want my graph to be like that.

I want my graph to be shown like ordinary line charts.

In other words, I want the data to be like this. But in this graph my dates are wrong.

[image: I want the data to be like this. But in this graph my dates are wrong.]

When I try to change the data series in the y axis then my chart becomes same like the first picture.
I'm a beginner and I don't know how to ask questions too. So if there is something that anyone don't understand from my question please ask me again. It'd be so great if someone clear my question.

Comment: One thing that would help your question would be to make the **data** useful by editing your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Comment: Have you tried the Scatter with straight lines?